# Best way to draw a scrolling curved path onto a canvas

Tags: java, canvas, bitmap

I want to create an illusion of a moving road or path.

For fun, I was thinking about how this could be done:

1. draw the whole path out in an image and simply have the image scroll across the screen - this would be annoying to manually draw and eliminates the ability to have a random path.
2. generate a pixel thin line equal the to width of the path at the top of the screen and simply move the line down the screen to have it scroll. And constantly generate new lines at the top in a slightly different location.

This is all I could come up with, I'm sure there are much better ways. How would y'all do it?

Answer (score 1):

What about making a queue which stores the path with a maximum size. And then you just redraw it when it gets updated.

I think drawing the line again is comparable to drawing a full screen image in performance concerns. Furthermore it will take less memory.

Comment: so basically you are proposing #2 except with the individual path-width lines prestored in an array rather than generated at run-time? And by redraw do you mean shifting the location of each path-width line down by a pixel, adding a new line at the top from the prestored array, then redrawn?

Comment: it doesnt have to be prestored. use a circular buffer and every time you push a new pixel, u drop the last pixel (not visible from now on). could be run-time generated too. the index in the array could represent the position on the pixel then. or you just shit every position in the buffer.